# Unable to infer complex closure return type using if let statement

Tags: arrays, swiftui, conditional-statements

**Problem**: Unable to handle nil when unwrapping an Optional, so I decided to use an if let statement because I receive the error in title.

**Goal**: I would like to have the foreach loop skip over generating an AnimatedImage object if urlString is nil.

```
HStack {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { column in
                if let post = self.observed.posts[safe: (row * 3 + column)] {
                    AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: post.image)).resizable().frame(width: self.width, height: self.width)
                }
                
            }
        }
```

I have created an extension to handle out of bound errors for arrays which leads to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if let` statement is not allowed in SwiftUI 1.0 (as well as `switch` btw). Your case is possible to solve with view private helper function, like below (scratchy, `cause snapshot is not testable, but idea should be clear)

```
private func image(in column: Int) -> some View {
    let post = self.observed.posts[safe: (row * 3 + column)]
    return Group {
       if post != nil {
          AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: post.image))
             .resizable().frame(width: self.width, height: self.width)
       }
    }
}
```

and now in

```
ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { column in
    self.image(for: column)
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help. I need to remember to use private func more often